# Routing form submits to home page view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, simple-form

I have a form to collect names and emails to be stored for my mailing list and am having an issue with my routes.

I am using rails 4 with simple form and when the user hits submit they are automatically redirected to the "list" of all the details entered this is standard, I would like them to be routed to the home page instead?

I have basically generated a scaffold for this 'temporary' data collection, I am also wondering if there is a gem to handle this better?

I have been going round in circles for a while now any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class DetailsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_detail, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
 @details = Detail.all
end

def show
end

def new
 @detail = Detail.new
end

def edit
end

def create
 @detail = Detail.new(detail_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @detail.save
    format.html { redirect_to @detail, notice: 'Detail was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @detail }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @detail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @detail.update(detail_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @detail, notice: 'Detail was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @detail }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @detail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def destroy
@detail.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to details_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private
def set_detail
  @detail = Detail.find(params[:id])
end

def detail_params
  params.require(:detail).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email)
end
end
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'legal/terms'

get 'legal/privacy'

get 'static_pages/about'

get 'static_pages/faq'

resources :details

get 'profiles/show'

devise_for :users

devise_scope :user do
get 'register', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register
get 'signin', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :signin
end

resources :statuses

resources :news

get 'welcome/index'

get '/:id', to: 'profiles#show'
```

simple for initializer

```
# Use this setup block to configure all options available in SimpleForm.
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
# Wrappers are used by the form builder to generate a
# complete input. You can remove any component from the
# wrapper, change the order or even add your own to the
# stack. The options given below are used to wrap the
# whole input.
config.wrappers :default, class: :input,
hint_class: :field_with_hint, error_class: :field_with_errors do |b|
## Extensions enabled by default
# Any of these extensions can be disabled for a
# given input by passing: `f.input EXTENSION_NAME => false`.
# You can make any of these extensions optional by
# renaming `b.use` to `b.optional`.

# Determines whether to use HTML5 (:email, :url, ...)
# and required attributes
b.use :html5

# Calculates placeholders automatically from I18n
# You can also pass a string as f.input placeholder: "Placeholder"
b.use :placeholder

## Optional extensions
# They are disabled unless you pass `f.input EXTENSION_NAME => :lookup`
# to the input. If so, they will retrieve the values from the model
# if any exists. If you want to enable the lookup for any of those
# extensions by default, you can change `b.optional` to `b.use`.

# Calculates maxlength from length validations for string inputs
b.optional :maxlength

# Calculates pattern from format validations for string inputs
b.optional :pattern

# Calculates min and max from length validations for numeric inputs
b.optional :min_max

# Calculates readonly automatically from readonly attributes
b.optional :readonly

## Inputs
b.use :label_input
b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :hint }
b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }

## full_messages_for
# If you want to display the full error message for the attribute, you can
# use the component :full_error, like:
#
# b.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
end

# The default wrapper to be used by the FormBuilder.
config.default_wrapper = :default

# Define the way to render check boxes / radio buttons with labels.
# Defaults to :nested for bootstrap config.
#   inline: input + label
#   nested: label > input
config.boolean_style = :nested

# Default class for buttons
config.button_class = 'btn'

# Method used to tidy up errors. Specify any Rails Array method.
# :first lists the first message for each field.
# Use :to_sentence to list all errors for each field.
#  config.error_method = :first

# Default tag used for error notification helper.
config.error_notification_tag = :div

# CSS class to add for error notification helper.
config.error_notification_class = 'error_notification'

# ID to add for error notification helper.
# config.error_notification_id = nil

# Series of attempts to detect a default label method for collection.
# config.collection_label_methods = [ :to_label, :name, :title, :to_s ]

# Series of attempts to detect a default value method for collection.
# config.collection_value_methods = [ :id, :to_s ]

# You can wrap a collection of radio/check boxes in a pre-defined tag, defaulting to none.
# config.collection_wrapper_tag = nil

# You can define the class to use on all collection wrappers. Defaulting to none.
# config.collection_wrapper_class = nil

# You can wrap each item in a collection of radio/check boxes with a tag,
# defaulting to :span. Please note that when using :boolean_style = :nested,
# SimpleForm will force this option to be a label.
# config.item_wrapper_tag = :span

# You can define a class to use in all item wrappers. Defaulting to none.
# config.item_wrapper_class = nil

# How the label text should be generated altogether with the required text.
# config.label_text = lambda { |label, required, explicit_label| "#{required} #{label}" }

# You can define the class to use on all labels. Default is nil.
# config.label_class = nil

# You can define the class to use on all forms. Default is simple_form.
# config.form_class = :simple_form

# You can define which elements should obtain additional classes
# config.generate_additional_classes_for = [:wrapper, :label, :input]

# Whether attributes are required by default (or not). Default is true.
# config.required_by_default = true

# Tell browsers whether to use the native HTML5 validations (novalidate form option).
#  These validations are enabled in SimpleForm's internal config but disabled by default
# in this configuration, which is recommended due to some quirks from different browsers.
# To stop SimpleForm from generating the novalidate option, enabling the HTML5   validations,
# change this configuration to true.
config.browser_validations = false

# Collection of methods to detect if a file type was given.
# config.file_methods = [ :mounted_as, :file?, :public_filename ]

# Custom mappings for input types. This should be a hash containing a regexp
# to match as key, and the input type that will be used when the field name
# matches the regexp as value.
# config.input_mappings = { /count/ => :integer }

# Custom wrappers for input types. This should be a hash containing an input
# type as key and the wrapper that will be used for all inputs with specified type.
# config.wrapper_mappings = { string: :prepend }

# Default priority for time_zone inputs.
# config.time_zone_priority = nil

# Default priority for country inputs.
# config.country_priority = nil

# When false, do not use translations for labels.
# config.translate_labels = true

# Automatically discover new inputs in Rails' autoload path.
# config.inputs_discovery = true

# Cache SimpleForm inputs discovery
# config.cache_discovery = !Rails.env.development?

# Default class for inputs
# config.input_class = nil

# Define the default class of the input wrapper of the boolean input.
config.boolean_label_class = 'checkbox'

#  Defines if the default input wrapper class should be included in radio
# collection wrappers.
# config.include_default_input_wrapper_class = true

# Defines which i18n scope will be used in Simple Form.
# config.i18n_scope = 'simple_form'
end
```

I hope thats the right simple form file you were after?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Post your `Controller code` and also your `simple_form` code

Comment: also post your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Whats the best way to share these?

Comment: simply edit you question. there is an `edit` button there. copy and paste code from `controller` and the corresponding `view`

Comment: by the way, the view form we are looking for is located at `app/views/details/` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def create
  @detail = Detail.new(detail_params)

 respond_to do |format|
   if @detail.save
     format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Detail was successfully created.' } #this is where the redirection is happening. change @detail to root_path
     format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @detail }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @detail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: You are a legend! thanks so much for that, so simple but i was never going to find it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the redirect statement at the end of the action in the controller which your form is posting to.

For example, if you've got a form such as:

```
<%= form_for current_user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit 'Save Changes' %>
<%= end %>
```

You want to keep the changes to `current_user` happening in the `UsersController`. You just want the response to the form submission, to land the user on your `root_path` as defined in your routes. You accomplish this by adding a `redirect_to` in your `UsersController` action.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    # ...
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: I kind of understand, however I dont have a "UsersController" my user is defined in profiles. If this data collection is to be separate to the user signing up would the changes above be in the "DetailsController"   def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ detail.update(detail_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @ detail, notice: 'Detail was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @detail }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json {render json: @ detail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

Comment: also why is this done on the update and not the create? If the redirect is to occur when the user enters their details on first visit?

Comment: This was just an example. You need to make this change in the controller which your specific form is posting to. In your case it looks like you need to make your changes in `DetailsController`. If you are making a new record, as it sounds like you are, you'll need to  make this change in the `create` action of your `DetailsController`. You will also need to define your `root` route in your routes file: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root

Comment: redirection is needed when in `create`, `update`, and `destroy` actions. you can choose different routes to redirect to but the idea is the same